# Search for duplicates in the column-values of each row / Compare column values row by row

Tags: r, duplicates, dataframe, data.table, dplyr

I have a very large DF, the structure looks like this:

```
route_1 route_2 route_3 route_4 route_grey_1 route_grey_2
A       B       NA      NA      NA           NA
A       B       C       NA      A            NA
A       B       C       D       A            D 
A       B       C       NA      C            NA
B       C       E       F       B            C
```

However,`A,B,C,D`  will be different between the rows.
For each row, I am trying to find the two values of route_1 to route_4 that are not mentioned in route_grey_1 and route_grey_2.
This will always be exactly 2 values. (if there are only two values in route_n there wont be an route_grey_n value, if there are three values in route_n than there is exactly one value in route_grey_n, etc.)

So the above input should lead to this output (adding two new columns:

```
route_1 route_2 route_3 route_4 route_grey_1 route_grey_2  result1 result2 
A       B       NA      NA      NA           NA            A       B  
A       B       C       NA      A            NA            B       C
A       B       C       D       A            D             B       C  
A       B       C       NA      C            NA            A       B
B       C       E       F       B            C             E       F
```

So far, the only solution that came to my mind was to write a function, looping through all rows and comparing one after another route_n with route_grey_n.
First, I think there might be a much better solution and I expect the loop to be very slow. Second I couldn't make my loop work, so if you think that might be the only solution, hopefully somebody can help me out there.

/e: While David's answer works for a small DF, it does take 30min on my data and fails:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 380 Kb
Error during wrapup: cannot allocate vector of size 438 Kb
```

I suspect there should be a solution using the dplyr or data.table packages.

/e2: After playing around with dplyr I managed to find a solution. It seems to work and takes ~30sec on my DF. However it is very hacky and might not be a very good one. Therefore any improvements are highly appreciated. Here my code:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(index) %>%
mutate( c_route1 = !route_1 %in% c(route_grey_1,route_grey_2),
c_route2 = !route_2 %in% c(route_grey_1,route_grey_2),
c_route3 = !route_3 %in% c(route_grey_1,route_grey_2),
c_route4 = !route_4 %in% c(route_grey_1,route_grey_2))
```

This creates columns with logicals in df, and then it gets ugly (probably this part can be done much nicer, would love to see some alternative):

```
df$result1[df$c_route1] <- df$route_1[df$c_route1]
df$result1[!df$c_route1 & df$c_route2 ] <- df$route_2[ !df$c_route1 & df$c_route2 ]
df$result1[!df$c_route1 & !df$c_route2 ] <- df$route_3[ !df$c_route1 & !df$c_route2 ]
df$result2[df$c_route1 ] <- df$route_2[ df$c_route1 ]
df$result2[!df$c_route1 & df$c_route2  ] <- df$route_3[ !df$c_route1 & df$c_route2   ]
df$result2[!df$c_route1 & !df$c_route2  ] <- df$route_4[ !df$c_route1 & !df$c_route2  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

As much as I'm trying to avoid `apply`, this is the only solution I could think of

```
DF[c("result1", "result2")] <- t(apply(DF, 1, function(x) x[1:4][t(!(x[1:4] %in% x[5:6]))]))

#   route_1 route_2 route_3 route_4 route_grey_1 route_grey_2 result1 result2
# 1       A       B    <NA>    <NA>         <NA>         <NA>       A       B
# 2       A       B       C    <NA>            A         <NA>       B       C
# 3       A       B       C       D            A            D       B       C
# 4       A       B       C    <NA>            C         <NA>       A       B
# 5       B       C       E       F            B            C       E       F
```

Comment: this does what I want, thanks.Can you explain the code? I dont fully understand it. Also it is, as expect with a loop/apply approach, very slow.

Comment: The code is quite simple. It goes over every row and checks which entries in `DF[i, 1:4]` are not in `DF[i, 5:6]`, and then prints these values.